# Only showing one of each title from the table

Tags: php, sorting

The web page I am talking about is http://transfigurationstattoostudio.com/showcase.php The table is made up of ID (unique), TITLE, DESCRIPTION, IMAGE_1, IMAGE_1_DESCRIPTION (plus five other slots for images)

The web page currently displays the thumbnail of each IMAGE_1, linking through the TITLE field to the full gallery.

What I am trying to do is remove duplicate TITLE entries, so the user can add several galleries with he same title, but only have one appear on the page (all images witht eh same title appear in the full gallery)

I tried using DISTINCT, but each record is unique, having a different ID. Is what I want even possible?

Comment: sorry ...but ..design is horrible

Comment: Normalize your database. At least It should make it easier.

Comment: can you GROUP BY TITLE ?

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT DISTINCT(title), image_1 FROM table;`

Though it should be stated that you shouldn't consider items with the same title a gallery. Why not create an addition table that references the image id's with a gallery id?

```
--Image
id | title | thumb1 | thumb2

--Gallery
id | title | description

--GalleryImage
gallery_id | image_id
```

This could even go another step forward and have another relationship for thumbs, instead of using thumb1 / thumb2 - but you get the point hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try two queries, one looping through all distinct titles and the second getting the first image record for that title. You didn't say your table name so I'll assume it is IMAGES:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);
$titleSql = "SELECT DISTINCT TITLE FROM IMAGES ORDER BY TITLE";
$result = $mysqli->query($titleSql);
while ($row = $mysqli->fetch_row($result)) {
    // Now just get the first image record associated with that title
    $imageSql = "SELECT ID, IMAGE_1 FROM IMAGES WHERE TITLE = " + $row[0] + " LIMIT 1";
    ...
}
```